# GWTP Invalid attempt to reveal errorplace, but then works normally

Tags: gwt, gwtp, gwt-platform

I have a couple of places set up, and they work correctly, except with a delay caused by this issue.  They're using nested presenters.
For one place, it appears that any repeat attempt to load it causes an infinite loop of reveal error / unauthorized place (no idea why, no gatekeeper set), but then loads the page correctly.  The issue I have with it is the delay and unnecessary log spam it causes - it loads the page correctly, why can't it do it without going through the loop first?  Anyone have any ideas?

-- UPDATE --

I am using GWTP 1.4 with GWT 2.7.0, but the project was first created using GWTP 0.6 or maybe earlier.  We've updated deprecation etc as we've upgraded, but I know there are anachronisms left.
I tried switching out our ClientPlaceManager with the default, bound the ErrorPlace and UnauthorizedPlace to our home page, and removed its gatekeeper, but it still tries to go to the error place (overrode the revealErrorPlace method and noticed it's throwing the error for a valid token that had been loaded at least once already that session.  One page in particular, none of the presenter lifecycle phases are firing, though the presenter is visible (only breaking in firefox I think).  I really don't understand it.

-- UPDATE 2 --

I've removed gatekeepers (even specifying @NoGatekeeper), have ensured that the error / unauthorized place have @NoGatekeeper and exists, and overrode revealPlace(request, updateUrl) to output results, and added a try/catch - and it does the exact same thing.  An infinite loop, but everything is accessible.  my debug output even shows it attempting to reveal the error place, but it never does, just errors out.
This is frustrating to no end.

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Exception caught: Encountered repeated errors resulting in an infinite 
loop. Make sure all users have access to the pages revealed by revealErrorPlace 
and revealUnauthorizedPlace. (Note that the default implementations call 
revealDefaultPlace)
com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: 
Encountered repeated errors resulting in an infinite loop. Make sure all users 
have access to the pages revealed by revealErrorPlace and 
revealUnauthorizedPlace. (Note that the default implementations call 
revealDefaultPlace)
    at Unknown.fillInStackTrace_0_g$(student-0.js@36:10580)
    at Unknown.Throwable_3_g$(student-0.js@8:10535)
    at Unknown.Exception_3_g$(student-0.js@18:10678)
    at Unknown.RuntimeException_3_g$(student-0.js@18:61481)
    at Unknown.UmbrellaException_3_g$(student-0.js@25:133542)
    at Unknown.UmbrellaException_5_g$(student-0.js@26:133603)
    at Unknown.fireEvent_7_g$(student-0.js@13:133134)
    at Unknown.fireEvent_12_g$(student-0.js@22:154354)
    at Unknown.fire_8_g$(student-0.js@17:132936)
    at Unknown.fireValueChangedEvent_0_g$(student-0.js@3:154358)
    at Unknown.onHashChanged_0_g$(student-0.js@29:154297)
    at Unknown.apply_0_g$(student-0.js@28:109006)
    at Unknown.entry0_0_g$(student-0.js@16:109062)
    at Unknown.anonymous(student-0.js@14:109042)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Encountered repeated errors resulting in 
an infinite loop. Make sure all users have access to the pages revealed by 
revealErrorPlace and revealUnauthorizedPlace. (Note that the default 
implementations call revealDefaultPlace)
    at Unknown.fillInStackTrace_0_g$(student-0.js@36:10580)
    at Unknown.Throwable_2_g$(student-0.js@8:10526)
    at Unknown.Exception_2_g$(student-0.js@18:10672)
    at Unknown.RuntimeException_2_g$(student-0.js@18:61475)
    at Unknown.startError_0_g$(student-0.js@11:92009)
    at Unknown.error_2_g$(student-0.js@8:91772)
    at Unknown.doRevealPlace_0_g$(student-0.js@10:91762)
    at Unknown.revealPlace_1_g$(student-0.js@8:91921)
    at Unknown.revealPlace_0_g$(student-0.js@8:91908)
    at Unknown.revealErrorPlace_1_g$(student-0.js@8:92109)
    at Unknown.error_2_g$(student-0.js@8:91773)
    at Unknown.doRevealPlace_0_g$(student-0.js@10:91762)
    at Unknown.handleTokenChange_0_g$(student-0.js@12:91848)
    at Unknown.onValueChange_4_g$(student-0.js@8:91888)
    at Unknown.dispatch_87_g$(student-0.js@16:132968)
    at Unknown.dispatch_88_g$(student-0.js@8:132972)
    at Unknown.dispatch_0_g$(student-0.js@8:49973)
    at Unknown.dispatchEvent_2_g$(student-0.js@14:133006)
    at Unknown.doFire_0_g$(student-0.js@9:133250)
    at Unknown.fireEvent_8_g$(student-0.js@8:133323)
    at Unknown.fireEvent_7_g$(student-0.js@25:133128)
    at Unknown.fireEvent_12_g$(student-0.js@22:154354)
    at Unknown.fire_8_g$(student-0.js@17:132936)
    at Unknown.fireValueChangedEvent_0_g$(student-0.js@3:154358)
    at Unknown.onHashChanged_0_g$(student-0.js@29:154297)
    at Unknown.apply_0_g$(student-0.js@28:109006)
    at Unknown.entry0_0_g$(student-0.js@16:109062)
    at Unknown.anonymous(student-0.js@14:109042)
```

Comment: Which version of GWTP are you using?
Did you set a DefaultGateKeeper?
Do you change place from prepareFromRequest methods?

Comment: I updated the question with versions and a bit more detail, but I'm using GWTP 1.4 with GWT 2.7.0.  The page / presenter that I first saw the issue on had no gatekeeper set, though I discovered another page that was throwing the error when using the browser back button from the original erroring page, and it had a gatekeeper.  I removed it, still with no luck.  There's no DefaultGateKeeper set.  It looks like it's an error, not an unauthorized problem - but I'm not sure how to get more details, I just have the stacktrace telling me soemthing went wrong

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the DefaultPlaceManager, make sure you have bound DefaultPlace, ErrorPlace and UnauthorizedPlace to Presenter name tokens in your Gin module.
From DefaultPlaceManager's javadoc (http://arcbees.github.io/GWTP/javadoc/apidocs/com/gwtplatform/mvp/client/proxy/DefaultPlaceManager.html):

> Important! If you use this class, don't forget to bind DefaultPlace,
>   ErrorPlace and UnauthorizedPlace to Presenter name tokens in your Gin
>   module.
>
> Note: The default, error and unauthorized places are revealed without
>   updating the browser's URL (hence the false value passed in
>   revealPlace). This will avoid stepping into an infinite navigation
>   loop if the user navigates back (using the browser's back button).
>
> Here's an example of infinite navigation loop that we want to avoid:
>
> An unauthenticated hits #admin (a place reserved to authenticated
>   admins) The #unauthorized place is revealed, and the browser's URL is
>   updated to #unauthorized The user clicks the back button in his
>   browser, lands in #admin, then #unauthorized, then #admin, and so on.

Also, from https://github.com/ArcBees/GWTP/issues/296:

> Verify that the Interface of the Proxy in your Presenter inherit from
>   ProxyPlace.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding - I suppose the real question is not why am I getting the loop (I know, I really should have an error place etc), but why is it even showing the error at all?  It's going to a valid place (overrode revealErrorPlace and added logging to get the error token), but it's trying to reveal the error place instead, and I don't understand why

Comment: I was using a custom placemanager ClientPlaceManager, but I'm still having the same issue when switching to the default and binding the places to a nametoken without a gatekeeper

Comment: 'Verify that the Interface of the Proxy in your Presenter inherit from ProxyPlace.' helped me - didn't check 'Create as place' in GWTP intellij plugin - a tough one to catch, thanks a lot!